# How can I update Tailwind without having to precompile assets every time? (Rails 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-ui

I'm using Rails 7 and Tailwind UI. Every time I add or change a tailwind class, I have to

> rake assets:precompile

to make it show the new styles. Is there a way to make it compile without that in Rails 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just have the same issue.
I fixed by using `./bin/dev` instead of `rails s`
And configure the `Profile.dev` file to the root of the project with this content:

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch
```

Bonus : I've installed this gem to have livereload: https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_live_reload

Comment: Don't work for me. :´(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'config.assets.debug = true' in development.rb